# Out of range value adjusted for column warning in django when adding a large integer (11 chars)

Tags: django

i get an "Out of range value adjusted for column"

not sure whether there is a fix for this in django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create custom field inhrited from Field or IntegerField

```
class BigintField(models.Field):
    def db_type(self):
        return 'BIGINT(20)'
...
```

and

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    bigid = BigintField()
```

Comment: It gives me the following error:psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:     "id" BIGINT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                       ^

Comment: I fixed it by changing BIGINT(20) to bigint , this is probably a postgres specific issue. If you could change your answer would be great, because I think your answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

For modern Django versions, use the `models.BigIntegerField`. It supports larger values.

Answer (score 2):

[Django ticket #399](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/399) deals with this. I also opened a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283724/big-integer-field-in-django-models) quite some time ago.

A workaround that I have used in the past is to simply `ALTER` the field in question directly in the DB table to `BIGINT` (for MySQL, for example). Note, however, that if you reset the application in which the particular model with the particular field exists, or drop the table and recreate it by any means, you will have to `ALTER` the field again.

Comment: hey, this is what i did and it worked, but somehow i feel this isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

For South users, django's built-in DecimalField may work better than the custom BigintField approach above.  Looks like it takes a bit of extra work to teach South about custom field types.