# Integer out of range

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an `integer out of range` error when trying to migrate my database from SQLite to PostgreSQL.

I think I have pinpointed the problem: I have some huge integers in a `IntegerField` field in  my model.

Basically on the order of 52675215334.

When I change this value to a small number like 1 and then try to migrate my database, all is fine.

Is there some other data type I should be using other than IntegerField to store these large values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big integer field in django models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283724/big-integer-field-in-django-models)

Comment: Those numbers are bigger than can fit in a 32 bit int.  Try "bigint" http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: SQLite has more slack than <insert dirty reference here>.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using [BigIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield) if you integers are *that* big. From the documentation:

> A 64 bit integer, much like an IntegerField except that it is guaranteed to fit numbers from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807. The admin represents this as an `<input type="text">` (a single-line input).

Comment: Thanks... in the end I realized I could actually store the value as a CharField since it's only used to append to URLs, but this would have worked too.

Comment: never would have guessed this in a million years...thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Change ***models.IntegerField()*** to ***models.BigIntegerField()***

```
class TableName(models.Model):
    ColumnName= models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to migrate the changes you did, otherwise it will not work

```
python manage.py migrate
```

python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31045871)